# RMySQL cannot connect to server from R

Tags: mysql, r

I want to connect to a MySQL database from R and I'm having some troubles. It is impossible to provide a reproducible example, but I hope someone can spot any mistake that I might be making.

This is the code I'm running in R:

```
library(methods)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
DB_name = "myDBname"
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user="myUser", password="myPassword", dbname="myDBname", 
                 host="my.host.something")
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error in mysqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my.host.something' (110)
```

I'm able to connect from the command line without any problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a conf file

```
gedit ~/.my.cnf
[someName]
user = myUser
password = myPassword
host = my.host.something
port=3306
```

Second, In R

```
library(methods)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
DB_name = "myDBname"
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, group= "someName", dbname=DB_name)
```